# Getshopped (WP-e-commerce): show all protucts on one admin page for drag-and-drop ordering

Tags: sort, plugin-wp-e-commerce

How I can show all my products on one page? I need drag-and-drop products from page 3 to page 1 but I can't do this over pages.

Or I can use another solution for manual product sorting?

[image: Getshopped (WP-e-commerce) products]

Comment: Is that generic [enough] admin screen? Usually you should be able to set amount of posts per page via "Screen options" (upper right corner of admin on the page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that generic [enough] admin screen? Usually you should be able to set amount of posts per page via "Screen options" (upper right corner of admin on the page).